# How to get PCI Devices by using VMK API (native) 2.2.0?

Tags: linux-kernel, vmware, pci, esxi

Trying to get access to a list of all PCI devices.

looking in VMK API (native) for an alternative function:

```
//VMK Linux API
struct pci_dev * pci_get_device_all(unsigned int vendor, unsigned int device, struct pci_dev *from)
{
   return pci_get_subsys_all(vendor, device, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, from);
}
```

thanks,

Alex

Comment: What's wrong with that function?

Comment: it doesn't exist in VMKAPI :| ...